# html <select multiple=multiple> + SQL Query Search

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a search based on

```
<select multiple=multiple name="chkUnr[]">
```

I'm getting out the values from select by running code:

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($_POST["chkUnr"]);$i++)
                    {
                    if($_POST["chkUnr"][$i] != "")
                    {
                        $search_country = $_POST["chkUnr"][$i];                     
                    }

            $query = "";
            $query .= "SELECT users.* FROM users";
            if (isset($_POST['singles_online']) ? $_POST['singles_online'] : 0 == 1) {
              $query .= " LEFT JOIN online ON online.user_id = users.id";
            }
            $query .= " WHERE";
            if (isset($_POST['vip']) ? $_POST['vip'] : 0 == 1) {
             $query .= " users.vip = 1 AND";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['profile_image']) ? $_POST['profile_image'] : 0 == 2) {
              $query .= " users.profile_image = '2' AND";
            }
            if (isset($_POST['singles_online']) ? $_POST['singles_online'] : 0 == 1) {
              $query .= " online.is_online = 1 AND";
            }
            $query .= " (id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users_blocked WHERE blocked_id = '$user_id')) AND";

            $query .= " (users.user_age >= '$age_from' AND users.user_age <= '$age_to') AND";

            $query .= " (users.gender = '$gender_search') AND";

            $query .= " users.country IN ('$search_country')";

            $search_query = mysql_query($query);


            }
```

And i can print out the values but the problem comes when i do the SQL search. 
It only pick up the first value in this case im using countries: 
So when i select Sweden, Germany, Usa i can print them all out but when trying to do a SQL query only Sweden is being picked up.

I've tried with this code but still same result.

Comment: What does a `var_dump($_POST)` look like?

Comment: I'm sorry, don't know what it is and where it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here (and with the other answer) is that the `in` clause was surrounded by quotes, so that will not yield the result that we want. We need to effectively pass in an array to the query. Also **your code is vulnerable to sql injection**. I would strongly suggest moving to PDO/prepared statements. I added a **slight** protection to the countries, but that is not foolproof by any means.

```
function prepareForSql($value, $key) {
    return addslashes($value);
}

array_walk($_POST["chkUnr"], "prepareForSql");
$search_country = "'" . implode("','", $_POST["chkUnr"]) . "'";

$query = "";
$query .= "SELECT users.* FROM users";
if (isset($_POST['singles_online']) ? $_POST['singles_online'] : 0 == 1) {
    $query .= " LEFT JOIN online ON online.user_id = users.id";
}
$query .= " WHERE";
if (isset($_POST['vip']) ? $_POST['vip'] : 0 == 1) {
    $query .= " users.vip = 1 AND";
}
if (isset($_POST['profile_image']) ? $_POST['profile_image'] : 0 == 2) {
    $query .= " users.profile_image = '2' AND";
}
if (isset($_POST['singles_online']) ? $_POST['singles_online'] : 0 == 1) {
    $query .= " online.is_online = 1 AND";
}
$query .= " (id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users_blocked WHERE blocked_id = '$user_id')) AND";

$query .= " (users.user_age >= '$age_from' AND users.user_age <= '$age_to') AND";
$query .= " (users.gender = '$gender_search') AND";

$query .= " users.country IN ($search_country)";

$search_query = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: This solution worked but this code needed to be modified:
$search_country needed to be modified first to:
$search_country = "" . implode("','", $_POST["chkUnr"]) . "";

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
            $search_country = implode(',',array_unique($_POST["chkUnr"]));

        $query = "";
        $query .= "SELECT users.* FROM users";
        if (isset($_POST['singles_online']) ? $_POST['singles_online'] : 0 == 1) {
          $query .= " LEFT JOIN online ON online.user_id = users.id";
        }
        $query .= " WHERE";
        if (isset($_POST['vip']) ? $_POST['vip'] : 0 == 1) {
         $query .= " users.vip = 1 AND";
        }
        if (isset($_POST['profile_image']) ? $_POST['profile_image'] : 0 == 2) {
          $query .= " users.profile_image = '2' AND";
        }
        if (isset($_POST['singles_online']) ? $_POST['singles_online'] : 0 == 1) {
          $query .= " online.is_online = 1 AND";
        }
        $query .= " (id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users_blocked WHERE blocked_id = '$user_id')) AND";

        $query .= " (users.user_age >= '$age_from' AND users.user_age <= '$age_to') AND";

        $query .= " (users.gender = '$gender_search') AND";

        $query .= " users.country IN ('$search_country')";

        $search_query = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: $search_country = implode(',',array_unique($_POST["chkUnr"])); 

If i select sweden and croatia the output is:
croatia,swedencroatia,sweden
Search results: 0 people found

Comment: if you look closely, i didn't use a for()... it isn't needed

Comment: Ahh yes better now. 
But i get results now if i select one country. But when selecting more then one country 0 results found. Any idea why?