# How can I feed input from a <select multiple> element into a (MySQL) stored procedure?

Tags: php, html, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

**Problem**

I would like a user to be able to select *multiple options* to search the database, (e.g. `WHERE field IN (optionA, optionB, optionC)`). The idea being that they select the options they would like in an HTML form, and then these options are passed to the stored procedure as parameters to be used in the `WHERE` clause.

---

**Example**

Let's assume we have experts who are *singular experts* - that is, they can each only be an expert in one technology. *(I'm aware this is a rather silly example, and one would never usually want to structure a database this way! Just an example :) )*

---

**Steps taken to develop a solution so far**

The first page displays a form allowing the user to select which technologies they are interested in.

```
<form action="showresult.php">
<select name="technologies[]" multiple>
    <option value="html">HTML</option>
    <option value="css">CSS</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option> 
    <option value="sql">SQL</option> 
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

showresult.php should `CALL` a stored procedure, passing it the parameters of all selected technologies.

```
*(I'm not sure how to do this)*
```

The stored procedure itself will take the potentially multiple technologies as an `IN` parameter to the stored procedure to use in a `WHERE IN` clause.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ExpertsInTechnologies(IN technologies VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Name, Technology 
    FROM 
        SingularExperts 
    WHERE 
        Technology IN ( ... technologies ... );
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Research so far**

- I have been searching Stack Overflow and found several *similar* questions, however they all achieve slightly different things, apply to other flavours of SQL, and/or I struggle to understand them. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821331/html-select-multiple-multiple-sql-query-search) describes a similar issue however the question (and answer provided) does not use prepared statements and is vulnerable to SQL injection.
- I updated the HTML so that the name `technologies` is `technologies[]` - so that it is passed as an array. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833330/how-to-get-php-get-array) tells me that to retrieve these values after they have been passed via `GET`, they can be accessed from `$_GET['technologies']`.

Comment: First step is to use `name="technologies[]"` so that an array will be passed in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Multiple will allow multiple to be selected but only the last item will be passed without `[]`.

Comment: Gotcha. Based on that here is an [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/23ji-x9y5) @Eilidh

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far, guys! I have updated my question accordingly based on your input.

Comment: Then just sanitize the `$_POST['technologies']` array and build a comma separated list of quoted values.  How depends on whether you are using PDO or MySQLI.

Comment: (After changing my search slightly) I see that this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149545/pass-array-to-mysql-stored-routine) also suggests that. Is this a safe way of doing so?